# Why is there an implicit type conversion from pointers to bool in C++?

Tags: c++, types, implicit, boolean

Consider the class `foo` with two constructors defined like this:

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo(const std::string& filename) {std::cout << "ctor 1" << std::endl;}
    foo(const bool some_flag = false) {std::cout << "ctor 2" << std::endl;}
};
```

Instantiate the class with a string literal, and guess which constructor is called?

```
foo a ("/path/to/file");
```

Output:

> ctor 2

I don't know about you, but I don't find that the most intuitive behavior in programming history. I bet there is some clever reason for it, though, and I'd like to know what that might be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the compiler choose bool over string for implicit typecast of L""?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316181/why-does-the-compiler-choose-bool-over-string-for-implicit-typecast-of-l)

Comment: Yet another similar question: [Function/Method Overloading C++: Data type confusion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636181/function-method-overloading-c-data-type-confusion)

Comment: Sorry. I did search (as I figured it would be a FAQ), but I didn't find any questions with a title that implied that the question was about this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's very common in C to write this

```
void f(T* ptr) {
    if (ptr) {
        // ptr is not NULL
    }
}
```

You should make a `const char*` constructor.

Comment: Surely you mean `if (!ptr) return;`? :) We wouldn't want our entire function nested of block more than necessary.

Comment: @GMan: Infuriatingly, I've actually had to *defend* that sort of return statement, because the powers that be decided that multiple return statements were inherently confusing and hard to follow, and enshrined that belief in the coding standards.

Comment: @Cascabel • there are programming languages which do not allow multiple return points in a function.  At one time, there was an industry movement for structured programming and flowchart design, which discouraged multiple return points in a function.  Then those principles were (mis?)applied to languages where ostensibly multiple return points are okay (doubly so, when you consider try/throw/catch as exceptional flow control).

Comment: @Eljay: It's unfortunate that people don't realize that what "one return point" means that any particular invocation of a function should always return *to* the same point, which is in contrast to the design of many pre-structured programs where various spots int the main loop would jump to "subroutines" which wouldn't return, but would instead jump to other spots in the main loop.

Comment: @supercat • Drat, I am one of those unfortunate people.  *Mea culpa!*

Comment: @Eljay: I don't fault you for that.  A lot of people don't realize that phrases like "Goto considered harmful" were uttered in response to program structures which by today's standards would be considered unimaginably bad, literally (many people today would be unable to imagine what such code was like).  Although I've written some such code myself in very constrained environments where the cost of normal subroutine overhead would have unacceptable, I appreciate very much the vastly more common situations where I don't have to do so.

Comment: @Eljay: For example, one of my projects included a diagnostic monitor which needed to allow someone with a terminal connected to perform RAM reads and writes to diagnose problems on a system which might have *zero* bytes of working RAM (the monitor itself ran from ROM, and kept its state entirely in the registers of an 8088-compatible CPU).  The code was ugly, but on a system with no RAM and only eleven 16-bit registers not counting the program counter, code segment, or status register, things like the "get character" or "output character" routines had to have a lot of exit points.

Comment: @Eljay: Incidentally, one of the more widely used exit points for "output character" would exit by jumping to the address in a particular register, which meant it could be used like a subroutine, but there were other exit points for "check if another register is bigger than 1; if so, convert the bottom 4 bits to a hex digit, shift it right four, and jump back to the output character routine; otherwise, jump to the address given in the same register used by the output-character routine [so output character, output hex byte, and output hex word, along with output string, etc. could...

Comment: ...all be treated roughly like functions on a machine with one level of stack [save for the need to manually load the return address before each "call"], but those other functions could use the output-character code without needing a second level of stack.

Answer (score 5):

You're passing a char* to the foo constructor. This can be implicitly converted to a boolean (as can all pointers) or to a std::string. From the compiler's point of view, the first conversion is "closer" than the second because it favours standard conversions (i.e. pointer to bool) over user provided conversions (the std::string(char*) constructor).

Answer (score -1):

You're confusing two issues.  One is that `"blah"` can be implicitly converted to a `string` and the other is that `const char*` can be implicitly converted into a boolean.  It's very logical to see the compiler go to the implicit conversion which minimizes the total amount of conversions necessary.

Comment: I was just giving an example that I felt would be common to encounter - my question was _why_ the implicit type conversion to `bool` happens with pointers.

Comment: There's only one conversion in either case.