# How do the operators < and > work with pointers?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, comparison, operators

Just for fun, I had a `std::list` of `const char*`, each element pointing to a null-terminated text string, and ran a `std::list::sort()` on it. As it happens, it sort of (no pun intended) did not sort the strings. Considering that it was working on pointers, that makes sense.

According to the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/sort/) of `std::list::sort()`, it (by default) uses the `operator <` between the elements to compare.

Forgetting about the list for a moment, my actual question is: How do these (>, <, >=, <=) operators work on pointers in C++ and C? Do they simply compare the actual memory addresses?

```
char* p1 = (char*) 0xDAB0BC47;
char* p2 = (char*) 0xBABEC475;
```

e.g. on a 32-bit, little-endian system, `p1` > `p2` because `0xDAB0BC47` > `0xBABEC475`?

Testing seems to confirm this, but I thought it'd be good to put it on StackOverflow for future reference. C and C++ both do some [weird things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111495/why-is-there-an-implicit-type-conversion-from-pointers-to-bool-in-c) to pointers, so you never really know...

Comment: Yes, they simply compare memory addresses.

Comment: Endiadness isn't relevant here. p1 > p2 whether big/low endian.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, but it was fun to write DABOBCAT and BABECATS with hex chars, so I ignored the not-so-greatness of the example...

Comment: It's interesting that all of the sorting algorithms in `<algorithm>` and `std::list::sort` use `operator<` by default (I just had to look that up; I would have figured they would use `std::less` by default).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C++, you can't compare just any pointers using the relational operators.  You can only compare two pointers that point to elements in the same array or two pointers that point to members of the same object.  (You can also compare a pointer with itself, of course.)

You can, however, use `std::less` and the other relational comparison function objects to compare any two pointers.  The results are implementation-defined, but it is guaranteed that there is a total ordering.

If you have a flat address space, it's likely that pointer comparisons just compare addresses as if they are integers.

(I believe the rules are the same in C, without the comparison function objects, but someone will have to confirm that; I'm not nearly as familiar with C as I am with C++.)

Comment: Comparing 2 pointers always compares the addresses as integers.

Comment: @Zac: A pointer is not an integer, and you cannot compare it as such.

Comment: It is an integer representing an address location.  And you can (though, comparing 2 addresses of completely separate entities seems a bit silly) compare them.  In fact, anytime you do `if (p != NULL)`, that is EXACTLY what you are doing.

Comment: @FredOverflow, yeah - isn't anybody here old enough to remember near and far pointers?

Comment: @Zac, NULL is a special case that is guaranteed by the compiler. All other comparisons to integers would be worrisome. I'm not enough of a language lawyer to say how worrisome.

Comment: @Zac: Can you provide a standard source for "Comparing 2 pointers always compares the addresses as integers."?

Comment: @Mark:  You can write `char* p1 = new char;  char* p2 = new char; if (p1 == p2) { // do something }`  and it is performing an integer comparison on the 2 addresses.  Doing `char* p1 = new char; if (p1 == 4) { // do something }` is legal and compiles ... even if it isn't very useful.  Comparing pointers does nothing more than compare the memory addresses using integer of the addresses.

Comment: @James: Is `std::less` specialized for pointers, or how else would it make a difference to use `std::less` instead of good old `operator<`?

Comment: @Zac: That's not legal, you cannot compare a pointer to an integer. You're simply wrong, pointers are not necessarily integers, they are their own type with an implementation-defined representation.

Comment: @FredOverflow:  Yes; `std::less` provides a total ordering for pointers.

Comment: @Gman:  Sorry, the second listing was meant to say `if (p1 == (char*)4)`.  See section 5.4.7 of the C Programming Language for reference.

Comment: @Zac: (1) You aren't guaranteed `(char*)4` is a valid value. (2) That's a book, not a standard. (3) C doesn't have `new`, but your code samples do.

Comment: @Zac: for a specific (if hypothetical) case where pointers are *not* just compared as integers, consider an implementation with two completely separate memory spaces, "red" and "blue". Suppose that a bit indicates which space the address is in: a "red" pointer, converted to integer, has the top bit set, whereas as "blue" pointer doesn't. There is nothing in the standard to say whether "red" pointers compare less or greater than "blue" ones using `std:less`, or if they're mixed together. So they need not be compared "as integers". They're compared as pointers, in an implementation-specific way.

Comment: @Zac:  Just because it compiles doesn't mean it's correct or even legal.  Don't use your compiler to tell you what is and is not OK or true about C++.  Use the Standard.

Comment: ... So James's qualification "it's likely" is correct. There is no guarantee I can see in the standard that pointer comparison, integer comparison, and pointer-integer conversion, are mutually consistent. However, you'd *expect* an implementer to make them consistent, especially on a flat memory architecture, by using sensible opcodes for the architecture. If they are consistent, then that's what I'd call "comparing them as if they're integers". There's still a difference between comparing them as signed vs. unsigned integers, and the standard only cares which if an object spans a +/- cutoff.

Comment: @John:  I never said it was okay; I said this is how it functions.  I even said it isn't very useful to do so.  The OP's question was, "operators work on pointers in C++ and C? Do they simply compare the actual memory addresses?"  Not "What does `std::less` do?".

Comment: @Zac:  You said "Comparing 2 pointers always compares the addresses as integers."  That's false.

Comment: As others previously mentioned, pointer < > operations are meaningful in an array.  Assume x[5]. x[i] is the same as *(x + i).  x[i+1] likewise is *(x + i +1).  The 2nd element clearly has a higher pointer value.

Comment: @Zac: `std::less` does whatever it takes to provide an ordering over pointers. On systems with a simple flat memory model, that is just "compare the pointers as if they were integers", but on other systems, it may have to do something more complex. `operator <` compares positions within an array, according to the spec, and that is guaranteed to work in the special case of arrays (which are guaranteed to be contiguous), but on some systems it may yield "weird" results if used on arbitrary pointers.

Answer (score 8):

This is just a supplementation.

In C++ 20.3.3/8:

> For templates greater, less,
>   greater_equal, and less_equal, the
>   specializations for any pointer type
>   yield a total order, even if the
>   built-in operators <, >, <=, >= do
>   not.

In C 6.5.8/5:

> If two pointers to object or
>   incomplete types both point to the
>   same object, or both point one past
>   the last element of the same array
>   object, they compare equal. If the
>   objects pointed to are members of the
>   same aggregate object, pointers to
>   structure members declared later
>   compare greater than pointers to
>   members declared earlier in the
>   structure, and pointers to array
>   elements with larger subscript values
>   compare greater than pointers to
>   elements of the same array with lower
>   subscript values. All pointers to
>   members of the same union object
>   compare equal. If the expression P
>   points to an element of an array
>   object and the expression Q points to
>   the last element of the same array
>   object, the pointer expression Q+1
>   compares greater than P. **In all other
>   cases, the behavior is undefined**.

So, I think comparing `char const*` which belong to two different '\0'-terminated-string as in the question is an undefined behavior (in C).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they just compare memory address.