# C++ STL comparing maps cannot find (operator==)

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to compare two `std::map`'s and the compiler is rejecting it because it can't find an (==) operator.

`1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\utility(275): error C2678: binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const foo::Value' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

An example follows.

```
namespace foo {
    struct Key { int k; };
    struct Value { int val; };
    typedef std::map<Key*,Value> Map;
}

bool operator==(const foo::Value &v1, const foo::Value &v2)
{
    return v1.val == v2.val;
}
bool operator!=(const foo::Value &v1, const foo::Value &v2)
{
    return !(v1 == v2);
}

bool compare(foo::Map &to, const foo::Map &from)
{
    return to != from;
}
```

1. If I rip out the namespaces, it works.
2. If define the == operator as a member, it works.

For example:

```
struct Value {
    int val;
    bool operator==(const Value &v) const { return val == v.val; }
    bool operator!=(const Value &v) const { return val != v.val; }
};
// elide the other == and !=
```

What am I doing wrong?  For my case, I'd prefer the `(==)` functions be local to the compilation unit rather than in the interface.

Comment: Why is your key a pointer?

Comment: This was intended (I am mapping pointers).

Comment: "(I am mapping pointers" - I can see that, I asked "why"?

Comment: It's an analysis algorithm that is relating information with some existing  objects. I don't understand why this is an odd use of an associative container. Is there a better way (without modifying `Value`)?

Comment: I asked because the behaviour may nor be exactly what you expected - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607418/how-do-the-operators-and-work-with-pointers for example. Also, if you erase something from the map what happens to the thing pointed to by the key?

Comment: Yeah, I expect keys to be compared as integers; I don't really care about the exact ordering (e.g. I could have used an unordered map). Also the map dies long before the keys get deleted. I understand the concern you raise though; it's a fair one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put the operators inside namespace `foo` then it works.