# Overloading operator< doesn't work for pointer of a claas

Tags: c++, class, pointers, operator-overloading

How do I overload the operator "<" to work with pointers pointing to classes?

Operator< for static classes works correctly but for pointers it doesn't return the right answer and seems not work at all.

```
class Point
{
    int x, y;

public:

    bool operator< (const Point* &p) const 
    { 
        if (x == p->x)
            return y < p->y;
        else
            return x < p->x;
    }
    bool operator< (const Point &p) const 
    { 
        if (x == p.x)
            return y < p.y;
        else
            return x < p.x;     
    }

    Point (int a, int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
};
```

Here I test the overloading function. In both cases my program should return `false`.

```
    Point* a = new Point(1,2);
    Point* b = new Point(0,0);

    Point c = Point(1,2);
    Point d = Point(0,0);

    cout<< boolalpha << (a<b) << '\n';  <- always returns true
    cout<< boolalpha << (c<d) << '\n';  <- returns false
```

Comment: The first overload declaration declares an `<` overload between a "`Point`" and a "pointer to Point". It is not an overload of `<` between two "`pointers to Point`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot overload operators for just built in types like `operator+(int, double)` or `operator<(int*`, `int*)`. This is simply not possible. In fact, the behavior of `(a<b)` is unspecified because you are comparing two unrelated pointers (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44397830/10147399) answer for more details). But you can:

1. Dereference the pointers before comparing.
2. Create a named function like `comparePointPointers` and use it as a regular function.
3. Create smart pointers, wrap them around your pointers, overload operators to compare them.