# Convert char to bool (passing bool to main)

Tags: c++, boolean, program-entry-point

Is there a recommended/correct/safer way to pass a bool argument to your main function?

Are this

```
$ ./my_software true
```

with this as `my_software`:

```
int main(argc, argv* []){

    bool my_bool = argv[1];

    return 0;
}
```

and this

```
$ ./my_software 1
```

with this as `my_software`:

```
int main(argc, argv* []){

    bool my_bool = atoi(argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

equivalent? Am I missing a conversion in the first one?

Comment: The fact that you can pass in "true" or "false", but also "dunno", "potato" or nothing, should be a hint that some processing is indeed needed.

Comment: You're not only missing a conversion in the first program, but `atoi` only handles integers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ streams can handle this. Don't forget to check that `argv[1]` actually exists !

```
#include <sstream>
//...
std::stringstream ss(argv[1]);
bool b;

if(!(ss >> std::boolalpha >> b)) {
    // Parsing error.
}

// b has the correct value.
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5adebe421331e92b)

Putting in the `std::boolalpha` stream manipulator enables parsing "true" and "false", leaving it out will let it parse "0" and "1".

Comment: Thank you, I already had a function checking argc, and I could neatly incorporate your example into it, providing both the check I was looking for and a way to assign the argument inside my function. Also, I never seen Coliru before, +1 for that!

Answer (score 1):

As for correct ways to do it, there's a lot. But there are unsafe/incorrect ways that you propose. First you are not guaranteed that `argv` is of length 2 or higher, you have to check `argc` before even looking at `argv[1]` (or anything in `argv`.

Second you're not guaranteed to get particular content in `argv[1]` even if it does exist. It could be **any** string, not only the expected `"0"` or `"1"` (it could even be the empty string) so just running it through `atoi` is probably not a wise choice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're missing a conversion on the first example, and most compilers should issue a diagnostic. The code won't work anyway, even if it compiles, because it tries to convert a raw character pointer to a bool value, and won't even look at the contents of the string.

Comment: So how do I deal with this? Is there such a thing as atob()?

Comment: Why should the line `bool my_bool = argv[1]` issue a warning? `argv[1]` has pointer type, and pointer types can be implicitly converted to `bool` (see [Why is there an implicit type conversion from pointers to bool in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4111495/1889329)).

Comment: To answer the OP's question, the most pedantically correct answer would be "bool value=atoi(argv[1]) != 0;". As far as warnings go, most compilers offer an option to issue warnings even for certain approaches that might be kosher by the book, but lead to confusion (such as mixing && and || in a boolean context, without explicitly slapping parenthesis to make their relative priorities clear). That's what I was referring to. Even if this is correct, by the book, it looks confusing to me.

Comment: `atoi("true") == atoi("false") == 0`. Your proposed *"pedantically correct anwer"* is incorrect. And I'm not being pedantic here. Use a [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to convert `"true"`/`"false"` to a `bool` value.