# Prevent implict object construction from bool?

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-construction

I have a class, `X`, and it has the following constructors:

```
class X{

    X(int64_t, int16_t, bool, int8_t);
    X(int64_t, int16_t, bool);
    X(double);
    X(double, FT);

    explicit X(const string&); 
    X(const string&, Y);
};
```

The problem is the compiler once created an X object passing just a bool (presume it was the double constructor which allowed this?) and it caused an issue.

To prevent this I made the bool constructor explicit and deleted it:

```
explicit X(bool) = delete;
```

but now I get compiler errors:

```
EXPECT_EQUALS(X("9.8901099"), a/b);
EXPECT_EQUALS(X{"56267"}, x);
X x{"-56267E-1"};
X b("5");
```

where the compiler says I have made use of deleted function `explicit X(bool) = delete`

**How do I prevent an object of X being created from a bool?**

Comment: This is working as intended. Say `X b("5"s);` or `X b(std::string("5"));` if you want the string constructor, or add overloads for `char const *`.

Comment: @KerrekSB but if I remove deleting the explict bool constructor, the above code all compiles?

Comment: If you explicitly delete the bool constructor, then it is used in overload selection and when it is the best match it becomes used, giving a compiler error then because it is deleted. You shouldn't need to explicitly delete it, because it's not like the compiler goes around implicitly declaring bool-constructors.

Comment: @MicroVirus are you saying I shouldn't have deleted the bool constructor? All I am trying to do is prevent an X object being created from a bool?

Comment: I'm not saying directly that you *shouldn't*, but I'm trying to tell you what happens if you explicitly delete it. It's up to you to decide if you want it.

Comment: I am confused, why would deleting a constructor then make it used in overload selection? Shouldn't deleting it just stop its usage? How can I prevent these objects being created from bool, using what I have shown above?

Comment: I don't think you understand what it means to declare a function as deleted. It's still declaring the function, and it will thus participate in overload resolution! It doesn't "remove an overload", it *adds* an overload.

Comment: You're telling me deleting something "adds" it? Thats not very smart, is it?!

Comment: You aren't deleting the declaration, you say there is no valid definition with delete.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111495/why-is-there-an-implicit-type-conversion-from-pointers-to-bool-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `bool` is a better match for `const char[]` than `std::string`. When you have no ctor accepting `bool` then the `std::string` one is chosen. When you have a ctor with `bool` then this overload is selected. Only it is deleted so it is illegal to call it.

Lets see this behavior with a simple free overloaded function:

```
auto foo(int) { cout << "foo int" << endl; }
auto foo(std::string const &) { cout << "foo string" << endl; }

auto main() -> int {
  foo(3);       // int
  foo("Asdf");  // std::string
}
```

When you add a `bool` overload:

```
auto foo(int) { cout << "foo int" << endl; }
auto foo(std::string const &) { cout << "foo string" << endl; }
auto foo(bool) { cout << "foo bool" << endl; }

auto main() -> int {
  foo(3);      // int
  foo("Asdf"); // bool (also warning implicit conversion turn string literal into bool)
}
```

The solution is to add a `char const *` overload:

```
auto foo(int) { cout << "foo int" << endl; }
auto foo(std::string const &) { cout << "foo string" << endl; }
auto foo(char const *s) {
   cout << "foo char const *" << endl;
   // possibly:
   return foo(std::string{s});
}
auto foo(bool) = delete;

auto main() -> int {
  foo(3);      // int
  foo("Asdf"); // char const *
  foo(true);   // error
}
```

Because some legacy code uses and returns `char *` instead of `char const *` you might need to add a `char *` overload too.

Comment: So basically what I have done is correct, but I either need to create an explicit char* constructor, or I need to cast my unit tests to use string?

Comment: that would be a possible solution

Comment: Ah this is excellent, thank you! I understand now what is happening. One question though, to implement char*, does this mean I cannot use std::string{s}?

Comment: @user997112 ofc you can.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to understand what happens if you explicitly delete the bool constructor. It becomes available in overload selection and when it is the best match it becomes used, giving a compiler error then because it is deleted.

This is different from when you do not define it, in that you can indeed 'stop' boolean values from converting via an implicit conversion plus followed by a (different) constructor of your class `X`, because it is the best match for a boolean, so implicit conversions stop there.

Consider the usage of your class

```
X x("abc");
```

Without the deleted `bool` constructor, this selects `X(const string&)`.

With the deleted `bool` constructor, however, this will select the `explicit X(bool)`, which is also deleted so this gives a compiler error. The solution to this, as Kerrek SB said, is to define a constructor for `const char *` as well.

And indeed, if you don't delete the `bool` constructor then the following selects the `double`

```
X x(true);
```

via first conversion to `int` and then conversion to `double`.

So, you can choose either solution, to delete or not to delete, but you need to be aware of the consequences and the requirements. If you delete it, you need to supply a `const char *` constructor. If you don't delete it, then you need to live with the fact that `bool` can be used to construct an instance of your class.