# Passing int as bool argument in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, boolean, implicit-conversion

could someone explain what happens in this code:

**example here:** https://ideone.com/1cFb4N

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class toto
{
public:
    bool b;
    toto(bool x)
    {
        cout<< "constructor bool:" << (x ? "true": "false")<<endl;
        b = x;
    }
    ~toto() {}
};

int main()
{
    toto t = new toto(0);
    cout << "t.b is " << (t.b ? "true": "false")<<endl;
    t = new toto(false);
    cout << "t.b is " << (t.b ? "true": "false")<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
constructor bool:false
constructor bool:true
t.b is true
constructor bool:false
constructor bool:true
t.b is true
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222690/discussion-on-question-by-serge-passing-int-as-bool-argument-in-c).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there an implicit type conversion from pointers to bool in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111495/why-is-there-an-implicit-type-conversion-from-pointers-to-bool-in-c)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In this declaration

```
toto t = new toto(0);
```

the object `t` of the class type `toto` is initialized by the pointer returned by the expression `new toto(0)`. As the returned pointer is not equal to `nullptr` then it is implicitly converted to the boolean value true.

So in fact you have

```
toto t = true;
```

except that there is a memory leak because the address of the allocated object is lost. So the allocated object can not be deleted.

You could imagine the declaration above the following way.

```
toto *ptr = new toto(0)
toto t = ptr;
```

So the first line of this output

```
constructor bool:false
constructor bool:true
```

corresponds to the dynamically created object with the argument 0

```
new toto(0)
```

Then the returned pointer is used as an initializer and is implicitly converted to the boolean value `true` that is used to initialize the declared object `t`. So the second line shows the call of the conversion constructor (constructor with a parameter) with the value true.

There is no great difference between the above declaration and this assignment statement

```
t = new toto(false);
```

because again a pointer is used in the right hand of the assignment.

So the implicitly defined copy assignment operator converts the value of the pointer that is not equal to `nullptr` to the boolean value `true`.

This assignment you may imagine the following way

```
toto *ptr = new toto(false);
t = toto( ptr );
```

And again there is a memory leak.

From the C++ 14 Standard (4.12 Boolean conversions)

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer
> to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. **A zero
> value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
> to false; any other value is converted to true.** For
> direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be
> converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.

Comment: As as aside, this is why constructors taking a single argument should _always_ be marked `explicit`.

Comment: [the answer by @AlanBirtles demonstrates how to solve this issue by using `explicit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64252849/52074).

Comment: The title of the question implies that the question is about `new toto(0)`, not about initializing `t`.

Comment: Ahhh, C++ with its many, many, ***many*** lovely footguns laying all around.

Answer (score 20):

Any integer value is implicitly convertible to `bool`, with 0 converting to `false`, and all other values converting to `true`.

The same applies to pointers, with null pointers converting to `false`, and all others converting to `true`.

`toto t = new toto(0);` is equivalent to:

```
// Create new toto instance, convert 0 to false and assign to p
toto* p = new toto(0);
// Create toto instance on the stack and convert non-null pointer p to true
toto t = toto(p);
```

You can prevent these surprising conversions by marking single argument constructors as `explicit`, meaning they won't be allowed to be considered during implicit conversions:

```
class toto
{
public:
    bool b;
    explicit toto(bool x)
    {
        cout<< "constructor bool:" << (x ? "true": "false")<<endl;
        b = x;
    }
    ~toto() {}
};
```

Comment: **I almost always mark single argument constructors as `explicit` in my c++ classes (sort of a rule-of-thumb)**. Some IDEs will provide a template for new classes with the constructor marked `explicit` (ex: `qtcreator` create new class that inherits from `QWidget`).

Comment: it is interesting that `toto t = false;` is considered an implicit conversion although it is functionally equivalent to `toto t(false);`.  In particular, no assignment operator is executed, and the constructor is only executed once. I always thought it's just a matter of taste which form of initialization to use.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica yep, `toto t = toto(false);` is equivalent to `toto t(false);`, `toto t = false;` goes via an implicit conversion

Comment: I understand that types are convertible to false. But the question is why and who ordered such a conversion? I have a pointer, so if a pointer of compatible type is returned, why should it convert to bool and not use directly to reference the toto instance.... Hard to read from my c# habits...

Comment: @Serge it's much nicer to be able to write `if (object)` rather than `if (object != nullptr)`

Answer (score 19):

In this statement:

```
toto t = new toto(0);
```

in the expression `new toto(0)` you are allocating a `toto` with a default argument `0`. This `int` can be implicitly converted to the `bool` value `false`, and this calls the `bool` constructor, resulting in the output:

```
constructor bool:false
```

Then you are doing the assignment:

```
toto t = /* pointer returned by new */;
```

This pointer can be implicitly converted to `bool`, and since this pointer is not `nullptr`, it has a non-zero value. This combined with the fact that the `toto` constructor accepting a `bool` is not `explicit` means that the constructor from `bool` is called for `t`, resulting in:

```
constructor bool:true
```

and this makes the `b` member of `t` have the value `true`, and hence the next line of code results in the output:

```
t.b is true
```